# making a class readable with >> and writable with << operators

Tags: c++

I have an assignment question for my object orientated programming course that asks for the creation of a class.

I am a little stuck on this part of the questions

> The class must, however, be readable using the >> operator and writable using the << operator.  Do not use a friend function to overload the operators.  Instead create suitable read and write methods and then overload the operators using a non-friend function.

Comment: Did you try to write this? What are you stuck on?

Comment: What is the question? It's MIA. BTW: Your teachers idea to do double the work for no gain is hilarious.

Comment: Have you asked your instructor?  Note that the nature of the question you are asking here is one that seems to go against various best practices and attempted answers might be completely wrong for your homework.  Your teacher is trying to lead you down a specific path of pedagogy and we don't know what that path is.  Deviations from that path may make it harder to learn future material.

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void ReadFrom(std::istream &is)
    {
        // read values from 'is' as needed...
    }

    void WriteTo(std::ostream &os) const
    {
        // write values to 'os' as needed...
    }
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, MyClass &cls)
{
    cls.ReadFrom(is);
    return st;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyClass &cls)
{
    cls.WriteTo(os);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: How would you go about using this?

Comment: @Lenny: like this: `MyClass cls; std::cin >> cls; /* use cls as needed */` and `MyClass cls; /* populate cls as needed */ std::cout << cls;`

Comment: When I do that I receive an error "Invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'Customer')" where Customer is my class. I have a Customer.h where I declared WriteTo and ReadFrom then I have a Customer.cpp where I implement them a long with the other methods in my class.

Comment: @Lenny but did you also implement the `operator<<` and `operator>>` overloads as well? It sounds like you did not.

Comment: I did, istream& operator>>(istream &is, Customer &cls)
{
    cls.ReadFrom(is);
    return is;
} and the ostream one aswell, hmmm

Comment: @Lenny: Then there is no reason you should be getting an "invalid operands" error.  Feel free to post a new question showing your actual code.

Comment: here is my new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821684/using-cin-and-cout-to-populate-fields-of-a-class-c)