# Using cin >> and cout << to populate fields of a class C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have a class in `MyClass.h` defined like this:

```
#ifndef MyClass_h
#define MyClass_h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    string input
    void ReadFrom(istream &is);
    void WriteTo(ostream &os) const;
};
#endif /* MyClass_h */
```

`MyClass.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

void MyClass::ReadFrom(istream &is) {
    // put data into member 'input'
}

void MyClass::WriteTo(ostream &os) const {
    // output data in member 'input'
}

istream& operator >>(istream &is, MyClass &cls) {
    cls.ReadFrom(is);
    return is;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const MyClass &cls) {
    cls.WriteTo(os);
    return os;
}
```

`main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   MyClass c;
   std::cout << "Enter some input" << endl;
   std::cin >> c;
   return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to override the `>>` and `<<` operators so that `std::cin` can simply read data into the class member(s), and then `std::cout` can spit out all of the data in those members.

I do not want to use `friend` functions.

Right now, I am getting an error around the `std::cin >> c;` line that says:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'MyClass')

Comment: IMHO it's usually a good idea not to try to be overly clever with overloads. Maybe what you *really* want is a constructor that takes the data you read from the user that you can explicitly call once you know you have the data you need to construct the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler fails to see the operator overloads in your `main.cpp` translation unit, because the overloads are not found in that file, nor are they found in any of the `#include` files.  You need to declare both overloads in your `MyClass.h` file instead, after the `MyClass` declaration:

MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MyClass_h
#define MyClass_h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    string input
    void ReadFrom(istream &is);
    void WriteTo(ostream &os) const;
};

istream& operator >>(istream &is, MyClass &cls);    
ostream& operator <<(ostream &os, const MyClass &cls);

#endif /* MyClass_h */
```

You can leave the definitions as-is in your `MyClass.cpp` file.